# Setting PATH for updated Tex Live installation

Tags: environment-variables

What is the best way to add the path for an updated Tex Live installation?

Using

```
PATH="${tldir}/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
```

or

```
PATH="$PATH:${tldir}/bin/x86_64-linux"
```

That is, should PATH lead or follow the Tex Live path?

Comment: What is `tldir`? Directories earlier in the path are searched first, so if different executables in different directories have the same name, it will matter.

Comment: It is the directory where I installed Tex Live.

Comment: Does one customarily add directories at the end?  I have an old version of Tex Live and my installation is picking up the old one.

Comment: Do the first one if you might have other binaries with the same names as the new TeXlive ones but you want to use the newer ones by default. Use the second if you want to use the old binaries by default. If you only have one set of binaries with those names, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Directories added to the beginning of `$PATH` are searched first when the shell looks for an executable. It's dangerous because same-named executables will mask executables in later directories. Add your directory at the end of `$PATH`.

Comment: I have an old Tex Live and the latest.  How can I make `pdflatex` find the latest one?